# Understanding Javascript asynchronous setInterval in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, asynchronous, synchronous

The following code creates a canvas with a ball at the centre when the `init()` method is invoked by using a `setInterval`. When the `keydown()` event is fired the ball moves on X and Y axis (depending on what key the user has pressed). What I struggle to understand is what happens when a key is pressed.

Does the `setInterval` stop when a key is pressed to update the key value (`keyLeft`, `keyRight`, etc) and then resumes and takes the updated values into consideration

**OR**

Does the code inside the key event execute while the `setInterval` is in progress?

I 've read that `setInterval` is asynchronous while key events are synchronous and since Javascript is single threaded the second option can't be true, right? I could really use your knowledge on this one..

```
    <canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid black" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var Ball = {
            positionX: 200,
            positionY: 200,
            keyLeft: false,
            keyRight: false,
            keyUp: false,
            keyDown: false,
            init: function() {
                this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
                setInterval(Ball.draw, 10);
            },
            circle: function (x, y, fill) {
                this.ctx.beginPath();
                this.ctx.arc(x, y, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                if (fill) {
                    this.ctx.fill();
                } else {
                    this.ctx.stroke();
                }
            },
            draw: function() {
                Ball.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
                if (Ball.keyLeft) Ball.positionX -= 5;
                else if (Ball.keyRight) Ball.positionX += 5;
                if (Ball.keyUp) Ball.positionY -= 5;
                else if (Ball.keyDown) Ball.positionY += 5;
                Ball.circle(Ball.positionX, Ball.positionY, true);
            }
        }
        Ball.init();

        $('body').keydown(function (e) {
            var key = e.keyCode;
            if (key == 37) {
                Ball.keyLeft = true;
            } else if (key == 39) {
                Ball.keyRight = true;
            }

            if (key == 38) {
                Ball.keyUp = true;
            } else if (key == 40) {
                Ball.keyDown = true;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `e.which` is way more browser friendly, just saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript (in browsers) is an event-driven language.  Most of the time, nothing is being executed.  When an event occurs and the script has registered a listener for that particular type of event, the event is placed into a queue.  If some part of the script is currently being executed, it will not be interrupted - rather, when it completes, the browser will pull the next event from the queue and start executing the registered handler for it.

In your code, you are registering for two kinds of events: timer events (implicitly, using `setInterval`) and `keydown` events (explicitly, using jQuery, which uses `addEventListener`).  When a timer event fires, your `Ball.draw` method is executed.  If a `keydown` event arrives while it is running, it waits in the queue until `Ball.draw` finishes.  Then it is dispatched to the handler function you assigned.  And vice versa: if the `keydown` handler is in progress, 10 milliseconds pass, and a timer event occurs, the timer event has to wait until the `keydown` handler completes.    This is one reason why Javascript timers are inherently imprecise.

**Short version**: your `keydown` handler can execute in between executions of `Ball.draw`.  Any changes it makes to variables used by both functions will be visible to `Ball.draw` on its next invocation.

Comment: So basically when the `keydown` event arrives, the queue will look something like this: `ball.draw()`, `keydown`, `ball.draw()`, `keydown`, `ball.draw()`, `keydown` since it is basically called constantly while it is kept pressed. On the other hand, if a `keyup` event is introduced later the queue will be like `ball.draw()`, `keydown`, `ball.draw()`, `keyup`, `ball.draw()`, `ball.draw()`, `ball.draw()`, right? Btw, thank you for the amazing explanation! :)

Comment: You're welcome.  The queue ordering you describe is one of many possible orderings.  It's never safe to make assumptions about how events will be interleaved.  Of course, the browser guarantees certain constraints on related events (keydown will always precede keyup, for example).

Answer (score 2):

The setInterval method schedules an event for future execution but does not block until the time has elapsed and the method is invoked. The JS will block for the duration of the method invocation and stop blocking upon its completion.

The way this code is written, every 10ms the draw method will be invoked (which is faster than the browser can even render which is 60 fps or ~every 16ms). If a keydown event has taken place since its last invocation, the draw method will pick up that new boolean/setting and act appropriately.

See the [notes section on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Notes) for more info on timing

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript is single-threaded** so even if you have a multi-processor device javascript code will execute on that single thread.

**`setInterval` runs "asynchronously", but...** asynchronously doesn't mean code runs on a separate thread or processor.  It means your synchronous code and your asynchronous code are issued timeslices in a queue. And the one-and-only-one thread is sequentially servicing all slices in that queue.

**Your `setInterval` will try to execute every # ms but it will be blocked by other operations** and will only execute when the one-and-only thread is available. So `setInterval` is not guaranteed to execute at its specified interval.

**When a key (or mouse) event is triggered,** that event is put into the queue, but the key event handler is not called. That key event handler will run when its originating event's turn comes up in the queue.